# UIScrollView Pinch ZoomIn/out at certain location

Tags: iphone, ipad, gridview, uiscrollview, calayer

I want to make application like Solar Wether application. Please see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfgWkAuLvng).

I don't want code but want to know how can we achieve functionality like zoom in/out in this application.

Please suggest me how to do this. I had made some code and done some R&D work and found [this solution](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) but want to do exact animation like this app.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIScrollView and use all the touch events like touchesended,touchesbegan, touchesmoved.

If you want a specific location of that touch you can get the point where the touch happens and call your custom action.